# INNER JOIN on array of id's which returns array of objects by using sequelize raw query in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have data in the below format

```
{
    "userId": 1
    "stateId": 199,
    "productId": [
        1,
        2
    ]
    
}
```

I want to get this type of response by using a sequelize raw query, I can get a response for userId and stateId by using inner join,

```
const List = await db.sequelize.query(
    'SELECT `user`.`id` AS `user.id`,`user`.`role` AS `user.role`,`user`.`name` AS `user.name`,`state`.`stateId` AS `state.stateId`,`state`.`stateName` AS `state.stateName`,state`.`Specialization` AS `state.Specialization` FROM details,INNER JOIN user  ON `user`.`userId`=details.userId INNER JOIN state ON `state`.`stateId`=details.stateId WHERE ORDER BY ASC LIMIT :offset, :limit',
    {
        nest: true, mapToModel: true, replacements: {
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset
        }
    });
}
```

but cannot get it for a product from an array of IDs.

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "role": "USER",
        "name": "user1"
    },
    "state": {
        "stateId": 199,
        "stateName": "test",
        "Specialization": null
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "productName": "Test product 1"
        },
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "productName": "Test product 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize can convert included records into objects only. If MySQL can work with JSON than you can try to convert records to an array of values yourself.

Comment: Could you please include what have you tried?